# NivoLightbox autoplay youtube video

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, lightbox

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzrboNXdhH4" class="TESTER123" id="hello"><%= image_tag("youtube.png", id:"YouTube", class: "img-rounded") %></a>
```

I am using to following code to open the video in the fancy box, but I want the video the autoplay once it opens but its not working that way and also the video should not another suggested videos at the end. I tried appending in the video link "&autoplay=1" and "&rel=0" but its not working for me.

Can anyone help me ?

(sorry guys I forgot to mention that I am using NivoLightbox NOT Fancybox)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/5QZsG/1/

Comment: @anonymousxxx Yes I did try it and I have mentioned it in my question.

Comment: @SamBattat I checked that thread but it didnt help me.

Answer (score 5):

This question is pretty old, but in case anyone else comes across it, this works (tested with Vimeo, should work with youtube as well):

```
$('.TESTER123').nivoLightbox({
    afterShowLightbox: function(){
        src = $('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src');
        $('.nivo-lightbox-content > iframe').attr('src', src + '?autoplay=1');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Mehdiway or joshcartme -- where does this code go? I'm not really experience with javascript/jquery but tried putting this under the `$('a').nivoLightbox(); });` in my header with no luck.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out had to change the code from `$('a').nivoLightbox()` to `$('a').nivoLightbox({` in order to open it up for this. Works great now.

Comment: Glad you got it, and that's exactly right, it should just replace wherever you invoke nivoLightbox

Answer (score 0):

Setup fancybox like this, and it should work:

```
$('.TESTER123')
    .fancybox({
        helpers   : {
            media : true
        },
        youtube : {
            params : {
                autoplay : 1,
                showinfo : 0,
            }
        }
    });
```